# From Flex, change the value of an Actionscript 3 property inside a Flash SWF that has been Embedded into an icon

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, scripting, icons

Ok, so I've been toying with using Flash SWFs in Flex objects as icons and the like.  I can embed it just fine, but I would like more control over certain flash Actionscript 3 properties WITHIN the embedded icon - for example, to change the size of the icon (icon used in two spots, one should be small, the other large).

Once I get that figgured out, I also need to apply this to a TreeListItem's folderClosedIcon.  That, however, is kindof secondary at the moment.

Thank you for any attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to pass properties via the [flashvar](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html) property on your embed. This can also be done by passing the variables through the URL this way : `"my.swf?buttonSize=20"`.

However if you need to communicate with the SWF after it's been loaded you can initialize a javascript-swf bridge thanks to [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).